# Auto resize iframe from different domain?

Tags: javascript, theming

I already post a question regarding this issue but I haven't got any solid answer(s). Since we are not allowed to communicate inside the iframe due to "Same Origin Policy", which I almost give up due to all responses that there is no way to re-size the height of an iframe coming from different domain.

Being eager to solve the problem I searched for solutions and I found this [easyXDM](https://easyxdm.net/wp/) which looks like a solution to my problem. Any of you guys have an idea about this. In addition to that I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/cross-domain-iframe-resize) also.

I also tried [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117134126/http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/01/13/103518.aspx) but it keep refreshing the page and keep looping to add height. Looking forward to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd hate to say it, specially as the author of easyXDM, but http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/resize_iframe.html is kinda *the* way to do it if you need cross-browser (and especially IE6) support. If you're fine with only supporting more modern browsers, then using postMessage directly is not that hard.

Comment: ...really appreciate your effort to answer my query. your plugin is very cool but have a difficulty implementing in Drupal...any suggestions?